# Is it possible to use different implementation of Python, except of standard one in Gogle Cloud Functions?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cpython, pypy

I am new to Google Cloud Functions. I want to write a small but execution intensive application. I researched [doc](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/first-python) and it is unclear if I can use PyPy or CPython when deploying to Google Cloud Functions.

Comment: There are only a few supported runtimes: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#runtimes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In function, you can't customize the runtime, [it is standard](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/python-runtime) to the service.

If you want more control on your environment, choose [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/), serverless but container based, and thus you can do what you want in your `Dockerbuild`.

In addition, you always have 1vCPU dedicated to the process with a customizable quantity of memory. With Cloud Functions, if you want to have the full power of the CPU you have to pay 2GB of memory. Finally, your process can take up to 15 minutes with Cloud Run but only 9 minutes with Cloud Functions.
I [wrote an article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-run-vs-cloud-functions-whats-the-lowest-cost-728d59345a2e) on this if you want to know more

Comment: It doesn't solve my question directly but it is a good workaround! Thx